# Error creating partition key using MergeTree engine, Clickhouse

Tags: python-3.x, docker-compose, sqlalchemy, clickhouse

I've been trying to create model using infi.clickhouse_orm but there have been an issue with partition key

My model:

```
from infi.clickhouse_orm import Model,  UInt16Field, Float32Field, StringField, MergeTree,DateField

class OHLC(Model):

__tablename__ = 'ohlc'

id = UInt16Field()
min = Float32Field()
max = Float32Field()


start_date = DateField()
interval = StringField()

engine = MergeTree(partition_key=['id'])
```

I get the error:

> DB::Exception: Syntax error: .. SETTINGS index_granularity=8192.
> Expected one of: Arrow, token, non-empty parenthesized list of
> expressions

[image: error]

creating my db

```
""" SqlAlchemy ClickHouse database session maker """

db = Database('test', db_url=os.environ['TEST_CONNECTION'],
              username=os.environ['CLICKHOUSE_USER'], password=os.environ['CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD'])
db.create_database()
db.create_table(OHLC)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MergeTree](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/)-engine required the *primary key* in the table declaration that passed in *order_by*-parameter:

```py
..
engine = MergeTree(partition_key=['id'], order_by=['id'])
..
```

---

```py
from infi.clickhouse_orm.engines import MergeTree
from infi.clickhouse_orm.fields import UInt16Field, Float32Field, StringField, DateField
from infi.clickhouse_orm.models import Model
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


class OHLC(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ohlc'
    id = UInt16Field()
    min = Float32Field()
    max = Float32Field()
    start_date = DateField()
    interval = StringField()
    engine = MergeTree(partition_key=['id'], order_by=['id'])


engine = create_engine('clickhouse://default:@localhost/test_001')

with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.connection.create_database()
    conn.connection.create_table(OHLC)
```

*requirements.txt*

```sh
sqlalchemy==1.3.18
sqlalchemy-clickhouse==0.1.5.post0
infi.clickhouse_orm==1.3.0
```

---

Using **id** as [partition key](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/custom-partitioning-key/) looks pretty suspicious, consider defining it as *toYYYYMM(start_date)* or something like this:

```py
class OHLC(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ohlc'
    id = UInt16Field()
    min = Float32Field()
    max = Float32Field()
    start_date = DateField()
    interval = StringField()
    engine = MergeTree(partition_key=['toYYYYMM(start_date)'], order_by=['id'])
```